# Data manipulation and structure in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, data-structures, data-manipulation

I have an '`Exp`' data set which looks like this:

```
  Locals   Res   Ind
1    112 7.865 4.248
2    113 4.248 5.666
3    114 5.666 2.444
4    115 2.444 7.865
5    116 7.865 4.248
6    117 4.248 6.983
7    118 5.666 3.867
8    119 2.444 2.987
```

And I have another data set called 'Com' as below:

```
113 112 113
112 114 119
116 118 119
118 118 119
117 117 119
117 117 119
```

Based on the value in the '`Com`' data set, I have pulled a corresponding value as part of the '`Res`' and '`Ind`' `matrix`.
For eg - The first value in the `Com` data set is `113` so in the `Res matrix` the first value will be `4.248` - because the corresponding value in Exp's first column of `113` is `4.248`. Such that the '`Res`' `matrix` looks something like this

```
4.248   7.865   4.248
7.865   5.666   2.444
7.865   5.666   2.444
5.666   5.666   2.444
4.248   4.248   2.444
4.248   4.248   2.444
```

Now based on the above '`Res`' data set, I want to deduct the first `row` by `2` and rest of the `rows` by `5`. Then I want to add up the values of the above data set based on the value of the `Com` data set. For eg there are two `113` in the Com data set, the corresponding values in the `Res` data set is `(4.248 - 2) + (4.248 - 2)`. So it is equal to `4.496`. The Output table should look like something below:

```
Locals  Dam
112 8.73
113 4.496
114 0.666
115 0
116 2.865
117 -3.008
118 1.998
119 -12.78
```

Can anybody please suggest a easy way to do this on R. If this is done on a list of data then what is the best way

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way with base to get you almost there:

```
Res = matrix(Exp$Res[match(Com, Exp$Locals)], nrow = nrow(Com))

subtract = Res
subtract[] = 5
subtract[1, ] = 2

Res = Res - subtract
output = data.frame(Locals = as.vector(Com), Dam = as.vector(Res))
output
#    Locals    Dam
# 1     113  2.248
# 2     112  2.865
# 3     116  2.865
# 4     118  0.666
# 5     117 -0.752
# 6     117 -0.752
# 7     112  5.865
# 8     114  0.666
# 9     118  0.666
# 10    118  0.666
# 11    117 -0.752
# 12    117 -0.752
# 13    113  2.248
# 14    119 -2.556
# 15    119 -2.556
# 16    119 -2.556
# 17    119 -2.556
# 18    119 -2.556
```

At this point, we just need to sum by group. There are many ways to do this, I'd encourage you to pick your favorite from the FAQ on [How to sum a variable by group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/903061) To avoid external dependencies, here's a way using the built-in function `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(Dam ~ Locals, data = output, FUN = sum)
#   Locals     Dam
# 1    112   8.730
# 2    113   4.496
# 3    114   0.666
# 4    116   2.865
# 5    117  -3.008
# 6    118   1.998
# 7    119 -12.780
```

At this point, if you really need the `0` entry for `115`, you could join to `data.frame(Local = unique(Exp$Locals))` or use `tidyr::complete` to fill in the holes. I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

> If this is done on a list of data then what is the best way

If you want to do this to a list of data frames, turn it into a function. If you have trouble with that, ask a new question providing a suitable sample inputs in a `list` - I'm not sure at this point whether you would want to use a list of `Exp`, `Com`, or both, so I won't make a guess here.

---

Using this data as input:

```
Exp = read.table(text = "  Locals   Res   Ind
1    112 7.865 4.248
2    113 4.248 5.666
3    114 5.666 2.444
4    115 2.444 7.865
5    116 7.865 4.248
6    117 4.248 6.983
7    118 5.666 3.867
8    119 2.444 2.987", header = T)

Com = as.matrix(read.table(text = "113 112 113
112 114 119
116 118 119
118 118 119
117 117 119
117 117 119"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This exercise can be solved in many ways, I will present one using some basic R functions that may come in hand.

- First the Res matrix, we can create it with a for loop and the which function in the following way.

  Resm <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(com), ncol = ncol(com))
  for (i in 1:nrow(com)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(com)) {
      Resm[i,j] <-Exp$Res[which(Exp$Locals==com[i,j])]
    }
  }
  Resm
- The subtraction is just simple matrix subtraction

  subM <- matrix(c(2, 2, 2,
                      5, 5, 5,
                      5, 5, 5,
                      5, 5, 5,
                      5, 5, 5,
                      5, 5, 5), ncol = 3,byrow=T)
  Resm2 <- Resm - subM
- The final answer is a function applied to the Res matrix based on the indices in the *com*, so:

  coms <- as.integer(names(table(com)))
  Dam <- sapply(coms, function(x){sum(Resm2[which(com==x)])})
  data.frame(Locals = coms, Dam)